# Is there any space objects database?

Tags: asteroid, technology, interplanetary, deep-space, stars

I wonder if is there any databse about space objects, giving information about types and may be relative positions of objects in space.

I'm asking this because my company aims to develop a software which will show space images, and I wonder if we can have another source but space photographs about modelling space. When images are not enough we could simulate space by having an information like "There is a star, this type, so it can be shown like that".

I hope I could explain my question. Thank you.

Comment: This question lacks any prior research, clear definition, and is as such too broad. There's literally hundreds, if not thousands of databases that fit your vague description. Here's a list of some (not exhaustive!) [star catalogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_catalogue). You might want to check [IAU MPC Orbital Elements for Software Packages](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/iau/Ephemerides/SoftwareEls.html) for minor bodies in the Solar system (they also have a few catalogs), and those that Pearson mentions. Or see [what others are using](http://www.skymaponline.net/instructions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number, usually broken down into 3 parts. I've included the 3 parts below, and a database where one might find information about these objects.

- Extra-solar objects- [SIMBAD](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/)
- Solar System Objects- [JPL Ephemerides](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?ephemerides)
- Satellites- Either [JSPOC](https://www.space-track.org/) or [Celestrak](https://celestrak.org/)

Comment: Also [space debris](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Operations/Space_Debris/ESA_makes_space_debris_software_available_online) databases.

Comment: I was looking for the same, and came across the HYG database (http://www.astronexus.com/hyg). There's a github project for the data.